# Disable background when custom confirmation message appears

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I 've built my own confirmation message as to have full control over it. My problem is how to disable the background (prevent user interaction with it) when this message appears. **I do not want to use jQuery or UI Bootstrap modals**.

```
<body>
<confirmation-message ng-if="showConfirmMessage">Changes have not been saved. Are you sure you wish to leave this page?</confirmation-message>


<script>
    angular.module('myApp',[])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$location', function($rootScope, $state, $location) {
        'use strict';
$rootScope.showConfirmMessage=false;
        var towardsState,towardsParams;

        $rootScope.$watch('changeState', function(newVal) {       
            if (newVal){   
                $state.go(towardsState, towardsParams);  
            }       
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            towardsState=toState;
            towardsParams=toParams;

            if ($rootScope.dirtyValueForm) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.showConfirmMessage=true;

                $rootScope.dirtyValueForm=false;
                $rootScope.changeState=false;      
            }

        });

    }])


.directive('confirmationMessage',  function($rootScope) {
            return {
               transclude:true,

               templateUrl:'app/shared/directives/confirmationMessage.html',
               link:function(scope,element){
                  element.on('click', function(event) { 
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if ($(event.target).text()==='Okay') {
                           $rootScope.showConfirmMessage=false;
                            ....
                        }
                        else if ($(event.target).text()==='Cancel') {
                           $rootScope.showConfirmMessage=false;
                            ...
                        }
                  });
               }
            };
        });
     </script>
    </body>
```

**confirmationMessage.html**

```
<div class="confirm-message" >
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button>Okay</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**and the css**

```
.confirm-message {
  position: fixed;
  top:220px;
  left:50%;
  z-index:1000;
  width: 400px;
  height:150px;
  padding:15px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #293C6E;
  color:white;
}
```

Do not examine thoroughly the code; it does work. For example, the value of `$rootScope.dirtyValueForm` comes from another controller. ***I want your help in disabling the background when the popup window (.confirm-message) appears without disabling the popup itself.***

Comment: usually it's done by having a div which takes the full width and height of the screen, positioned behind the dialog but in front of the content, which registers a click listener and call `stopPropagation` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a page-wide div element with a z-index higher than the background but lower than your confirm message. Have the div as a part of your directive with whatever class you want to assign to it, too.

Directive template:

```
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="confirm-message" >
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button>Okay</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.backdrop {
  z-index:500;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/HLSYl0pI2AZ15qf5T5WM?p=preview

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Place your confirm message outside of the container you wish to 'obscure', then apply something like:

```
.modal-container.obscured {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: blur('1.5px'); /* for extra credits */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to disable the whole body

Comment: @ILIAS - You will need to place the content you want to hide in another div. If you disable the body tag, everything on the page will be similarly disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your confirmation message inside a wrapper, which covers the whole page. The wrapper should have a z-index higher than the background and lower than the confirmation box.

```
.confirm-message-wrapper
{
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

    z-index: 900;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to trap events on this. It will only give the appearance of modality.